# R: better data structures and algorithms for a complex problem

Tags: r, algorithm

Sorry long question. I'm looking for suggestions on better data structures and algorithms for a complex problem. I am analyzing data to see why some Brandy varieties have quite different characteristics. There are substance groups (substanceG1 to substanceG12) that contribute to the differences. Depending on the quantities and varieties the substances are present in a Brandy, the drink can have distinct color, transparency, taste, aroma, etc.

Table 1 contains the Brandy and the amount of the substance groups:

```
Variety substanceG      Amount
BrandyA substanceG1     5.1
BrandyA substanceG2     1.2
BrandyA substanceG3     2.3
BrandyB substanceG1     1.1
BrandyB substanceG2     2.5
BrandyB substanceG7     3.0
BrandyB substanceG11    3.5
...
```

The components of the substance groups are in Table 2. All numbers are in percentage.
The components of the substance groups are in Table 2. All numbers are in percentage.

```
substanceG  A       B   C   D   E       F
substanceG1 0.8     1.1 51  0   47.1    0   
substanceG2 23.4    0   4   12  58.8    1.8
substanceG3 47.9    32  0   0   0       20.1
...
```

Each component is known to make certain contribution to the characteristics of the brandy (Table 3).

```
Trait       A   B   C   D   E   F
Color       3   0   2   1   5   5
Transpar    1   4   0   6   2   2
Taste       0   5   1   0   7   1
NuttyAroma  3   7   0   4   4   0
Dryness     7   0   2   6   0   2
```

All three tables above are simplified for clarity.

For each Brandy, the total contribution of the substance groups will be calculated for each trait. Take BrandyA. There is `5.1*0.8%` amount of component A in substanceG1. So `5.1*0.8%*c(3,1,0,3,7)` is A's contribution in substanceG1. There is `5.1*1.1%` amount of component B in substanceG1. `5.1*1.1%*c(0,4,5,7,0)` is B's contribution in substanceG1... Then add everything up: `5.1*0.8%*c(3,1,0,3,7)+5.1*1.1%*c(0,4,5,7,0)+...+5.1*0%*c(5,2,1,0,2)` and move onto substanceG2, 3, and so on. Alternatively, total amount of A in BrandyA can be obtained by `5.1*0.8%+1.2*23.4%+2.3*47.9%, B 5.1*1.1%+1.2*0%+2.3*32%`... Use the sums to multiply the respective columns in Table 3. After the multiplications the row sums are calculated. Those are the total contribution scores of all substance groups in BrandyA.

Either way works. I wrote a console script that relied on querying/conditional subsetting the tables and loops to do the math. It runs, but is slow and error-prone. Misspellings in the tables easily causes breakdown. There must be a better way, a more efficient way. How would you approach this problem?

Comment: matrix multiplication ... ????

Comment: Unfortunately, the tables are not homogeneous -- they contain columns of texts. So if those columns are removed, matrix operation is an option. A second obstacle is the text columns all have different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done pretty concisely with two joins, a multiplication, and summing those up. It will help to reshape the 2nd and 3rd table into longer format so that each row of the 2nd one corresponds to one substance-group combination and each row of the 3rd one corresponds to one trait-group combination. That way you can progressively join them to the preceding table to get a row for every Variety-substanceG-Trait in the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% pivot_longer(-substanceG)) %>%
  left_join(df3 %>% pivot_longer(-Trait), by = "name") %>% 
  mutate(contribution = Amount * value.x/100 * value.y) %>%
  count(Variety, Trait, wt = contribution)
```

Result:

```
  # A tibble: 10 x 3
   Variety Trait          n
   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 BrandyA Color      27.7 
 2 BrandyA Dryness    17.1 
 3 BrandyA NuttyAroma 22.8 
 4 BrandyA Taste      28.8 
 5 BrandyA Transpar   12.6 
 6 BrandyB Color      13.6 
 7 BrandyB Dryness     7.37
 8 BrandyB NuttyAroma 11.0 
 9 BrandyB Taste      14.7 
10 BrandyB Transpar    6.51
```

Source data:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Variety, ~substanceG, ~Amount,
  "BrandyA", "substanceG1", 5.1,
  "BrandyA", "substanceG2", 1.2,
  "BrandyA", "substanceG3", 2.3,
  "BrandyB", "substanceG1", 1.1,
  "BrandyB", "substanceG2", 2.5
  # "BrandyB", "substanceG7", 3.0,   # excluded b/c not in other tables
  # "BrandyB", "substanceG11", 3.5   # excluded b/c not in other tables
)


df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~substanceG, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D, ~E, ~F,
  "substanceG1", 0.8, 1.1, 51, 0, 47.1, 0,
  "substanceG2", 23.4, 0, 4, 12, 58.8, 1.8,
  "substanceG3", 47.9, 32, 0, 0, 0, 20.1,
)

df3 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Trait, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D, ~E, ~F,
  "Color", 3, 0, 2, 1, 5, 5,
  "Transpar", 1, 4, 0, 6, 2, 2,
  "Taste", 0, 5, 1, 0, 7, 1,
  "NuttyAroma", 3, 7, 0, 4, 4, 0,
  "Dryness", 7, 0, 2, 6, 0, 2
)
```

Comment: Hi Jon. The logic is sound. This is way better than my nested loops. I will try this on my larger data sets and report back. Appreciate the help!